# x86 assemby instruction mov [esp+0ACh+var_A4], eax

Tags: assembly, x86

I came across following x86 assembly instruction,

```
mov     [esp+0ACh+var_A4], eax
```

not able to understand it. As i can guess, it is saving the value present in `eax` register into address represented by `esp+0ACh+var_A4`. Not sure.
I am able to understand the following assembly instruction. It is quite obvious,

```
mov     eax, [ebp+0]
```

loading `ebp+0` into `eax` register. Please correct if I am wrong.

Comment: `mov     eax, [ebp+0]` moves the 4 bytes (since the detination is a 32-bit register) at address pointed to by EBP and stores it in EAX.

Comment: @MichaelPetch ya but how you can  `mov     [esp+0ACh+var_A4], eax` put this instruction?

Comment: @sushantyelpale: It's not really any different from `[ebp+0]` (from the assembler's and linker's perspective there are some differences, but you don't have to worry about that). In one case the offset is `0`, and in the other the offset is `var_A4+0ACh`.

Comment: `0ACh` and  `var_A4` are both offsets that are added together. The disassembler has broken them out to identify a data structure it appears. So `mov [esp+0ACh+var_A4], eax`.var+A4 will be the value of the offset of that variable. It moves the 4 bytes in EAX to the memory address pointed to by `esp+0ACh+var_A4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mind you have something like this:

```
typedef struct my_Struct {
   u_int8  x;
   u_int8  y;
   u_int16 z;
   u_int32 a4;
}

#define offs_x 0
#define offs_y 1
#define offs_z 2
#define offs_a4 4

myStruct myArray[SIZE];
```

and you want to access myArray[21].a4

in assembler there's no structs, and no arrays. you have to calculate the position of myArray[21].a4 by yourself. the array is just a memory block:

```
0000: myArray[0].x
0001: myArray[0].y
0002: myArray[0].z #1
0003: myArray[0].z #2
0004: myArray[0].a4 #1
0005: myArray[0].a4 #2
0006: myArray[0].a4 #3
0007: myArray[0].a4 #4
0008: myArray[1].x
0009: myArray[1].y
...
```

let's assume EBP is pointing to myArray

each element is 8 bytes long ( 1+1+2+4 bytes ), so myArray[21] is at EBP + 21*sizeof(my_Struct) = EBP + 172 (= EBP + ACh), and myArray[21].offs_a4 at EBP + ACh + offs_a4.

finally: To read myArray[21].a4, you'd have to

```
mov eax, [EBP + ACh + offs_a4]
```

this also works with ESP (ESP indicates you're dealing with local variables, that's memory usually has been reserved on the stack) in a funtion that's been called, and 0ACh is the offset to this variable

Comment: In C you don't even have to `#define` the offsets, you can use [`offsetof(struct my_Struct, z)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof).  Anyway, those #defines aren't something you'd ever do in C, so you should make them comments instead.

Comment: you're right. I just #defined them, to show where the 2nd offset is coming from. they don't harm :)